# Laravel 5.4 doesn't convert empty string to null

Tags: laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4 doesn't convert empty string like "" to null.
For Example when I create a route like this

```
Route::get('/string/trim' , function(){
   dd(request()->input('email'));
});
```

and call this url:

`http://example.com/string/trim?email=`

I see empty string in output not null value.

In the app/Http/Kernel.php file these lines of codes are also existed:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

TrimStrings are only for **form** elements, not for ***router query params***.